# Empty folder (with .gitignore in it) wont be pushed with cf-cli

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to include an empty folder with the name of `FolderShouldBePushed` to the cloudfoundry push. I am using the cf-cli version 6.34.1 which should fix problems with the .cfignore file. In the [release notes](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/tag/v6.34.0)([Issue to the fix](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/993)), it is stated that folders with a .gitignore in them should be pushed, even if they are empty.

In addition, I added the folder `FolderShouldBePushed` to the .cfignore file. My `.cfignore` file now looks like this.

```
!/TestParent/FolderShouldBePushed
```

And my folder structure looks like that:

[image]

So now I expect it to push the `FolderShouldBePushed` also, but when I ssh into the container I only get the `TestParent` folder with the `testFile.txt` in it and the`FolderShouldBePushed` is missing.

How do I achieve to push empty folders with the cf-cli?

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: @data_henrik When using laravel there is a folder called storage/framework/views. The folders in framework are empty when pushed, so the whole framework folder doesn't get pushed. If the views folder is missing, the site is not working.

Comment: Just to clarify, in your top directory is the `.cfignore` with the rule(s) on empty directories, correct?

Comment: yes the `.cfignore` is in my top-directory.